# knp paginator only works with array

Tags: symfony, doctrine, paginator, knppaginator

I am using Knp Paginator Bundle in Symfony 2.

i keep getting the following error when trying to pass a Doctrine query to the paginator:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object in /var/www/adwind/vendor/knplabs/knp-components/src/Knp/Component/Pager/Event/Subscriber/Paginate/Doctrine/ORM/QuerySubscriber.php on line 67 Call Stack: 0.0000 635448 1. {main}() /var/www/adwind/web/app_dev.php:0 0.0166 6042728 2. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle() /var/www/adwind/web/app_dev.php:25 0.2128 10057152 3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpKernel->handle() /var/www/adwind/app/bootstrap.php.cache:617 0.2129 10058808 4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() /var/www/adwind/app/bootstrap.php.cache:1566 0.2129 10058808 5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() /var/www/adwind/app/bootstrap.php.cache:1390 2.1839 21851024 6. call_user_func_array() /var/www/adwind/app/bootstrap.php.cache:1426 2.1840 21851640 7. Adwind\BannerBundle\Controller\BannerController->listAction() /var/www/adwind/app/bootstrap.php.cache:1426 2.2085 22257080 8. Knp\Component\Pager\Paginator->paginate() /var/www/adwind/src/Adwind/BannerBundle/Controller/BannerController.php:76 2.2173 22401584 9. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ContainerAwareTraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch() /var/www/adwind/vendor/knplabs/knp-components/src/Knp/Component/Pager/Paginator.php:97 2.2173 22403912 10. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch() /var/www/adwind/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ContainerAwareTraceableEventDispatcher.php:78 2.2175 22406864 11. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() /var/www/adwind/app/cache/dev/classes.php:5072 2.2176 22410128 12. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ContainerAwareTraceableEventDispatcher->doDispatch() /var/www/adwind/app/cache/dev/classes.php:4854 2.2254 22490968 13. call_user_func() /var/www/adwind/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ContainerAwareTraceableEventDispatcher.php:139 2.2254 22491024 14. Knp\Component\Pager\Event\Subscriber\Paginate\Doctrine\ORM\QuerySubscriber->items() /var/www/adwind/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ContainerAwareTraceableEventDispatcher.php:139
```

i am using the example from the github readme :

```
$em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$dql   = "SELECT a FROM AdwindBannerBundle:Banner a";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
$pagination = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate($query,$page,10);
```

Everything works fine if i pass the result array instead of the query itself.
ie :

```
$query = $em->createQuery($dql)->getResult();
```

But as far as i understand it you should be able to pass the query itself or even a query builder.
Also i imagine this way i am getting all the results instead of just one page.

ps : i am using dev-master version of the paginator bundle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a special version knp-сomponents in composer.json

"knplabs/knp-components": "1.2.1",

I think the current version has a bug

at least now it works for me

Comment: Hi, was unable to test this for a while :)
ive tested it now , it does actually work, i can pass a QueryBuilder or a Query now to the paginator.
so can see the results now.

however it seems that the knp_pagination_render twig function does not work now, so i cant see any pagination buttons .... again this works with arrays but not with querybuilder or query...

i tried reverting the knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle to 2.3.2 instead of dev-master, but no luck...

anyway i think im just going to not use knp paginator for now until the next release :) thx for the help !

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$query->select(array('b'))
        ->from('MyMainBundle:Customer', 'b')
        ->orderBy('b.updated_at', 'desc');

$paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$requests = $paginator->paginate($query, 
                                $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1), 5);
```

Currently paginator can paginate:

- array
- Doctrine\ORM\Query
- Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder
- Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Query\Query
- Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Query\Builder
- Doctrine\Common\Collection\ArrayCollection - any doctrine relation
  collection including
- ModelCriteria - Propel ORM query
- array with Solarium_Client and Solarium_Query_Select as elements

Comment: so strange... i tried your code, passing a query builder instead of a query and i keep gettings the same error, as soon as do a getResult() the error goes away...
must be something wrong with my installation ..
thanks for trying anyways ;)